# Pivot object on HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have the following simplified structure:

```
     [
      {
        "ClientId": 512,
        "ProductId": 7779,
        "Date": "2019-01-01",
        "Quantity": 20.5,
        "Value": 10.5
      },
      {
        "ClientId": 512,
        "ProductId": 7779,
        "Date": "2019-02-01",
        "Quantity": 15.5,
        "Value": 11.2
      },
      ...
    ]
```

It goes on until december and it have others `ProductsId`s with all the months of the year. What I want is to "pivot" it, without losing object reference and to look like this:

[image: full-table]

I am using Angular and any help it could do it's appreciate.

Comment: What do you mean: "_without losing object reference_"? A "Pivot" service would be appropriate that would store its own data structure when invoked - most appropriately though a (maybe "pivot") directive.

Comment: Unless you find a library for this, you'll have to write the loops yourself. Tip: divide everything per product first. ( 2D array, object, Map, ... )That way you can loop over all products, and for each product, loop over the 12 monthly objects to create a row.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Shilly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3049127/shilly) comment made me realise a solution, reducing the array of objects to an object using the `productId`s as keys, add the remaining values, and then map it back to an array again. Probably not the best one, but worked.

```
var o = this.products.reduce((prev, cur) => {
  prev[cur.ProductId] = prev[cur.ProductId] || [];
  prev[cur.ProductId].push(cur);
  return prev;
}, {});

this.valueWithMonths = Object.keys(o).map((k) => {
  return { productId: +k, values: o[k] };
});
```